# How do I make heroku stop creating a web process for a worker-only app?

Tags: node.js, heroku, procfile

I have a simple worker-only app that uses heroku's scheduler to run once per day. However I noticed that I was getting an extra run every time I pushed code and tracked it down to heroku creating a web process, running my worker command (twice!), and then declaring it "crashed" once my worker completes.

My Procfile only has one entry:

```
worker: npm start
```

But when I push to heroku, the logs include this little bit:

```
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types   -> worker
       Default types for Node.js -> web
```

What's going on here and how do I disable it?

You can see my complete code at https://github.com/nfriedly/vzw-bot and logs from a recent push at https://travis-ci.org/nfriedly/vzw-bot/builds/83548651

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40265699/is-it-possible-to-deploy-a-node-js-application-to-heroku-without-a-web-dyno

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a solution, running this will disable the default web worker:

```
heroku ps:scale web=0
```

The deploy logs still report the default web type, but it doesn't actually spin one up after that.

Comment: This works, but... is there really no way to override the "default types for buildpack" so it doesn't do a web process at all?

Comment: I've raised an issue for it here: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs/issues/335