# Is it possible to deploy a Node.js application to Heroku without a web dyno?

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

For some backstory and reference, here are some quotes from a few Heroku documentation pages.

From the [Heroku Node.js Support > Activation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#activation):

> The Heroku Node.js buildpack is employed when the application has a `package.json` file in the root directory.

From [Heroku Node.js Support > Default web process type](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#default-web-process-type):

> First, Heroku looks for a [Procfile](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile) specifying your process types.
>
> If no `Procfile` is present in the root directory of your app during the build process, your web process will be started by running `npm start`, [...]

From [Process Types and the Procfile > Process types as templates](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile#process-types-as-templates):

> A Procfile contains a number of process type declarations, each on a new line. Each process type is a declaration of a command that is executed when a dyno of that process type is started.
>
> For example, if a `web` process type is declared, then when a dyno of this type is started, the command associated with the `web` process type, will be executed. This could mean starting a web server, for example.

---

I have a `package.json` file in the root (which will activate the Node.js buildpack), and I've also included a `Procfile` in the root with the following contents:

```
service: npm start
```

I would assume that not defining a `web` dyno would cause it to not be created; only the `service` dyno should be created, following the configuration declared in the `Procfile`.

Instead, what happened is that an **active** `web` dyno was *automatically* created using `npm start` and an **inactive** `service` dyno was created using the definition in `Procfile`. I then had to:

- `heroku ps:scale web=0`
- `heroku ps:scale service=1`

I can definitely imagine wanting to run a Node.js "service" application on Heroku that does not accept any incoming connections, only making outgoing ones. Is there a way to configure the Node.js buildpack to not automatically create a `web` dyno when one is not defined? I've looked through lots of documentation looking for a way to either: **(1)** define it as such or **(2)** *remove* the automatically generated `web` dyno; but, I haven't found anything.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I ended up opening a helpdesk ticket with Heroku on this one. Got a response from them, so I'll post it here. Thanks Heroku support!

---

The short answer is that, no, currently you'll need to `heroku scale web=0 service=1` in order to run a service without a public `web` process. For a longer explanation:

Early on, the Node.js Buildpack checked for the presence of a `Procfile` and, if missing, created a default one with `web: npm start`. This made it easy to create apps without a web process, since you could just provide a `Procfile` that defined some processes, omitting `web` from the list.

However, as more and more users needed arrays of buildpacks instead of a single one, that solution created issues. Node is the most popular first buildpack, since it's frequently used by Java, Python, PHP, and Ruby apps to build front-end assets. Whenever an app without a `Procfile` ran Node first, and another buildpack second, Node would inject its own default `Procfile` (`web: npm start`), and the second buildpack would then not create its default `Procfile` as one already existed in the filesystem. So injecting a default Procfile when one is missing from the app creates problems downstream for multilingual apps.

So, we [stopped creating a default Procfile and instead used default_process_types in bin/release](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs/pull/231). This fixes the issue of subsequent buildpacks inheriting incorrect default Procfiles, but since `default_process_types` is *extended* rather than *replaced* by the `Procfile` process list, apps without a `web` process defined in their `Procfile` will get the default `web` process merged in. This is why `web` appears even without a `web` entry in `Procfile`.

We also don't want to surprise any customers with unexpected bills. Some apps have many process types, some of which are only to be run occasionally, some limited to a single instance, some which need to be scaled up and down, etc, so defaulting everything to 1 rather than 0 could cause extra billing as well as app malfunctions. This is why non-web processes are scaled to zero by default.

Answer (score 6):

I just ran into the same problem and worked it around doing this in my Procfile after reading Shibumi's answer:

```
web: echo "useless"
service: node index.js
```

Comment: I am trying to deploy docker and am using `heroku.yml` file instead of Procfile. Any idea what do i do in this case?

Comment: Ha! That's interesting. If going down that path, you could even maybe do something like `web: false` to just return `1` so that Heroku knows it "failed"; you might even get some feedback in the UI from a non-zero return value.

Comment: @MatejJ There looks to be some good information here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/build-docker-images-heroku-yml

Comment: Unfortunately this does not stop the `web` dyno spinning up (and staying on) which I believe is the intention of the question

Answer (score 0):

The actual correct whay to do it is running on your terminal:

```
heroku scale web=0 worker=1 --app YOUR_APP_NAME_HERE
```

It will disable `web` and set one `worker`

On your `Procfile` you must keep `worker: your-startup-command`